# How to send a pdf url in a custom attribute and download it after successful submission in Contact Form 7?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have different singles created by wordpress, in each single I have 2 divs that depending on the one being clicked (and a successful form submission), the pdf url attached in a custom attribute should download.

I assigned a 2 custom attributes called "data-download" and "data-type".
data-download contains the url of the pdf that should be downloaded and "data-type" contains the type of div.

Note: I will not have the same urls always, depending on the single created by the user, the url will change so just typing a normal/static url is not what I'm looking for.

Here are the divs:

```
<div class="btn-main" id="btn-manual" name="some-title" data-type="manual" data-download="some-url" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#download">Manual</div>

<div class="btn-main" id="btn-data" name="some-title" data-type="data" data-download="some-url" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#download">Data</div>
```

I tried getting it directly with the id but it only -always- downloads the file in the first if("manual" is always downloaded), it never enters the else. Because of that I'm not sure if the conditionals in the ifs are correct...

I used the function provided by Contact Form 7 in "Functions.php":

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
function mycustom_wp_footer()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event )
        {  
                if(document.getElementById('btn-manual').onclick)
                {
                    var divManual = document.getElementById('btn-manual');
                    var dwnld = divManual.getAttribute('data-download');
                    var title = divManual.getAttribute('name');
                    var filetitle = "Manual - " + title;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(document.getElementById('btn-data').onclick)
                    {
                        var divData = document.getElementById('btn-data');
                        var dwnld = divData.getAttribute('data-download');
                        var title = divData.getAttribute('name');
                        var filetitle = "Ficha_Tecnica - " + title;
                    }
                }

                download(dwnld, filetitle);
                function download(dataurl, filename)
                {
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = dataurl;
                    a.setAttribute("download", filename);
                    a.click();
                }
        }
}
```

I also tried using conditions so that if the "data-type" is the same as a const, it should download the file according to that div but it doesn't work...

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
function mycustom_wp_footer()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event )
        {  
            if ( '1134' == event.detail.contactFormId )
            {
                let div = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-main');
                let type = div.getAttribute('data-type');

                const manual = "manual";
                const data = "data";

                if (type === manual)
                {                  
                   let dwnld = div.getAttribute('data-download');//url of manual
                   title = div.getAttribute('name');
                   let filetitle = "Manual - " + title;
                }
                if (type === data)
                {
                   let dwnld = div.getAttribute('data-download');//url of data
                   let title = div.getAttribute('name');
                   let filetitle = "Ficha_Tecnica - " + title;
                }

                download(dwnld, filetitle);

                function download(dataurl, filename)
                {
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = dataurl;
                    a.setAttribute("download", filename);
                    a.click();
                }
            }
       }
}
```

The closest result I got was the first code I showed (since it actually downloads something) but I'm not sure if that is the general correct approach that i should take or even if the conditionals are correct...

Sorry but I'm a beginner...

Comment: You can't have an `onclick` check on if statement. That will always return true. Try adding `click` eventListener on the two buttons and do the necessary downloads. Your approach is fine except the fact that I won't have the download url on DOM. Because people can easily download it without submitting any form or clicking any button by just inspecting the DOM.

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan Thank you for your answer. I did try using an event listener, something like this: `document.getElementById("btn-data").addEventListener("click", function())` in each if yor each div, but it didn't work... For the url in the DOM, I'm not troubled by it, my concern is that the correct file cant be downloaded...

Comment: I will write an answer for you shortly. Sorry, I am on my mobile right now.